# Padrino/Sinatra: how modify response in "after" filter?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, response, padrino

I can't really get my head around it. Let's say I have a controller as follows:

```
get :test do
  status 201
  body "test"
end

after do
  status 404
  body "not found"
end
```

Now, visiting /test produces response with status 404 and body "test". How do I do this properly?

Also, I noticed I can omit *body* like

```
get :test do
  status 201
  "test"
end
```

and the response stays the same, but calling response.body later returns empty array instead of the actual content. Why is this so confusing, is that some kind of inconsistency between Padrino and Sinatra? What am I missing here, anyone care to explain?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: if you're doing this in an actual test scope (such as with capybara) - then this is a fairly well known issue.  response.body does not update quickly enough to give meaningful data during testing

Answer (score 0):

I presume you want to override the sefault Sinatra not found message ?
You could do that like this

```
get :test do
  "test"
end

error Sinatra::NotFound do
  content_type 'text/plain'
  [404, 'Not Found']
end
```